# Bootstrap 3 - Vertical align alongside pull-right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On the footer of http://moorparksdevon.uk I have some text an an image.
I've aligned the image with pull-right, but am struggling to vertically-align the text. No matter what I try, It won't vertical align without pushing other elements out.

Could I have some pointers in the right direction please?

```
<div id="footer" style="height: 45px;">
    &#169; Moorparks 2017 - Holiday cottages in North Devon
    <a href="http://facebook.com/moorparks"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/findusonfb.png" class="pull-right" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add `line-height: 25px;` to `div#footer` (`45px`footer height - `10px` padding-top & `10px` bottom = `25px`)

[image]

Comment: Thanks - However, I'm after vertically aligning the text rather than horizontally aligning.

(I took the pull-left out as that was a left over 'test' but thanks for pointing that out)

Comment: And I could have sworn I'd tried that. Thank you very much sir!